# Как вытащить определенное значение из map

Tags: java, map

Есть класс `Person`, он имеет три поля - `name`, `age` и `surname`. Я создаю `HashMap` из Person'ов и хочу вытащить все `surname` записать в отдельный лист.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Map<String, Person> book = new HashMap<>();
            Person person1 = new Person(29,"Петрова","Анна");
            Person person2 = new Person(34, "Сидорова", "Оля");
            Person person3 = new Person(34, "Тихонова", "Алла");
            Person person4 = new Person(35, "Петров", "Петр");
            book.put("Key1", person1);
            book.put("Key2", person1);
            book.put("Key3", person2);
            book.put("Key4", person3);
            book.put("Key5", person4);
            book.put("Key6", person4);

    }

    public static void takeSurnames(Map<String, Person> map) {
         List allSurnames = new ArrayList(); // Вот сюда я хочу записать все фамилии из map.
    }
}
```

Может кто подсказать как это сделать?

Comment: Если ответ решил ваш вопрос, то нажмите на галочку, чтобы принять его.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<String> allSurnames = map.stream()
        .map(Person::getSurname)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

или

```
List<String> allSurnames = new ArrayList();
for (Map.Entry<String, Person> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    Person person = entry.getValue();
    allSurnames.add(person.getSurname());
}
```